# What is the origin of the phrase "Let that sink in"

Tags: etymology

In my own research, I found some references as far back as 1905 but does anyone have the origin of the phrase "Let that sink in"?

Comment: This [Google Books search shows 2 hits from the 19th C](http://bit.ly/2mWasKp): 1837 in *[Australian] Parliamentary Debates, Volume 153* and 1895 in *A Memoir of George Higinbotham: An Australian Politician and Chief Justice*. But beware of dates when using Google Books; they're algorithmically extracted from an OCR of the work and can be unreliable. But it's interesting both the earliest hits are from Australia.

Comment: A *good* question will show and share their research. It will also explain why they are interested in discovering the word or phrase's history. Just idle curiosity is not a compelling enough reason.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The relevant definition for *sink* in this sense in the OED is this:

> To penetrate *into* (†*to*, *unto*, *through*), enter or be impressed *in*, the mind, heart, etc.

Under this definition, the earliest entry is from a1300:

> Sua sar þin sakes to for-thingk
>   þat soru thoru þin hert sink
>   <sub>[Cursor mundi](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/c/cme/AJT8128.0001.001/1:4.1.171?rgn=div3;view=fulltext)</sub>

I found that [the Middle English Dictionary](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/cgi/m/mec/med-idx?type=byte&byte=181222814&egdisplay=open&egs=181264699) has a lot of examples for this sense, under 3.(c).

As for the expression "let that sink in", a very similar expression can be found in this quote from 1385:

> Lat oure sorwe synken in thyn herte
>   <sub>[Chaucer: The Knight's Tale](https://sites.fas.harvard.edu/~chaucer/teachslf/kt-par1.htm)</sub>

And in this quote from 1422:

> In-to thyn herte let my wordes synke
>   <sub>[How to Learn to Die](https://books.google.com/books?id=tGQiRWIlgy0C&pg=PA201&lpg=PA201)</sub>

This same expression can be found much later, in this quote from 1798:

> It is concerning a truth, as our Lord faith, Luke ix. 44. "Let these thinks sink in your hearts:" so we say, let this truth sink in your hearts.
>   <sub>[The Ruin of Rome](https://books.google.com/books?id=tcI0AAAAMAAJ&pg=PA442)</sub>

The expression "let [it] sink in your hearts" appears to be the origin of the shorter expression "let that sink in".

The earliest I can find for "let that sink in" is from 1837:

> It appears, from the speech of the Leader of the Senate last night, that the only way in which the commission could supplement the work of the High Court would be in connexion with legislation which, while it might not infringe the provisions of the Constitution, might place one State at a disadvantage in relation to another. Let that sink in.
>   <sub>[Parliamentary Debates](https://books.google.com/books?id=bCQEAAAAMAAJ&q="let+that+sink+in")</sub>

After that, the next example I found is from 1895:

> Both times I noticed his masterly use of the pause. It was as if he would say, 'There, let that sink in.'
>   <sub>[A Memoir of George Higinbotham](https://books.google.com/books?id=8zlAAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA241)</sub>

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic expression ***[sink in](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sink--in)*** in the sense of  *being  understood* is quite old according to [The American Heritage  Idioms Dictionary](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/sink--in)

> - Penetrate the mind, be absorbed, as in *The news of the crash didn't sink in right away*. ***[Late 1300s]***

***Let that sink in*** is a set phrase which  derives from the above expression. Its earliest usages appear to be from the second half of the 19th century.  I think the 1837 usage example present in [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=let%20that%20sink%20in&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clet%20that%20sink%20in%3B%2Cc0) is a false positive.

[The Railway News](https://books.google.it/books?id=SgA1AQAAIAAJ&q=%22let%20that%20sink%22&dq=%22let%20that%20sink%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjF27j3-enYAhVHxxQKHVYuBMMQ6AEINzAE) ..., Volume 44 - 1885

> ***Just let that sink into your minds***. The Continental traffic via Dover and Calais and Folkestone and Boulogne has increased in much greater proportion during the existence of the Queenborough route than it did in the years before.

Comment: You can check if the 1837 citation is a false positive.

Answer (score 2):

In 1534, William Tyndale used the words :

> Let these sayinges synke doune into youre eares. Luke 9:44.

The Authorised Version copied his wording in 1611 :

> Let these sayings sink down into your ears.

[Textus Receptus - Tyndale and KJV](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/42009044)

The word 'sink' translates the Greek word τιθεμι, *tithemi*, meaning 'to place, lay or set down' [(Strong 5087)](http://biblehub.com/greek/5087.htm).

In 1175 the Wessex Gospels expresses the translation as :

> Asetteð þas spræce on eowren heorten

[Textus Receptus - Wessex Gospels](http://textusreceptusbibles.com/Interlinear/42009044)